# Camera Calibration Kinect Vision Caltech IR camera

Tags: matlab, camera, computer-vision, kinect, camera-calibration

So I was trying to calibrate the IR camera of the new Kinect v2 sensor. So I am following all the steps from here http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/htmls/example.html

The problem I am having is the following:
The IR image looks fine but once I put it through the program the image I am getting is a mostly white(bright) image. See pics below

Anyone encountered this issue before?

Thanks

[image: Before Putting through Camera Calibration Toolbox]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading the IR image pixels correctly. The format is 16 bits per pixel, with only the high 10 ones used (see specification [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj663793.aspx)). You are probably visualizing them as if they were 8bpp images, and therefore they end up white-saturated.

The simplest thing you can do is downshift the values by 8 bits (i.e. divide by 256) before interpreting them in a "standard" 8bpp image. 
However, in Matlab you can simply use imagesc to display them with color scaling.